# Counterexamples of reverse Fatou lemma

Tags: real-analysis, integration, examples-counterexamples, limsup-and-liminf

> If $\{f_n\}\subset L^+$, $f\in L^+$ Is it necessarily true that $$\limsup\int f_n\leq \int \limsup f_n?$$

I know if $f$ is dominated then this result is true: [Dual result of Fatou lemma](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1838693/dual-result-of-fatou-lemma)

But how about counterexamples of above statement without dominated.

Comment: What does $L^{+}$ mean?

Comment: @user284331 I'd guess its non-negative measurable, given the context

Comment: Then my funny example goes through.

Comment: @user284331 yes non-negative

Answer (score 4, accepted):

$f_{n}(x)=\dfrac{1}{n}$, $\displaystyle\int_{\mathbb{R}}f_{n}=\infty$, $\limsup_{n}f_{n}(x)=0$, $\displaystyle\int_{\mathbb{R}}\limsup_{n}f_{n}(x)=0$.